# file manager permission based on users on Ajenti

Tags: server, 15.10, files

I installed Ajenti-v on my Ubuntu server 15.10 and I want to create multiple users with specific access to their home directory.

Currently, whenever I create a new `ajenti` user (which is synced with OS Users), it can access to the whole file system.

How can I limit their access to a specific directory like `/home/user`?

There is an option within the *Configure > Plugins* section of the root user which will limit the access on all users's file managers, but it cannot be used for specifying directories for each users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found the solution [here](https://github.com/ajenti/ajenti/pull/789/files).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.